# Clipping video files

Tags: video, codecs, video-editor, encoding

I want to cut some video files I got, basically remove individual pieces of every video, without making some mashup or anything like it. I tried OpenShot Video Editor and AVIDEMUX. The latter got not-so-great interface, but is much easier for me, as I can cut out pieces and produce an output quickly, keeping the original codecs and quality (which I don't know how to properly handle and combine). Unfortunately, it is crashing quite a lot on some files, plus it never works with WMV files, that also get mute audio (audio v9).

So, I'd like some suggestions from you guys. I could keep using AVIDEMUX if I can get it working better, or some other app, preferrably as easy as it. With OpenVideo, besides taking a long time re-encoding the video, I frequently do bad codec selection and mess up output quality, plus it will force the output to some predefined size, which sometimes do not match the input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend openshot which i use to cut parts of several videos and them put the videos together (Very good when you want to make Ubuntu Tutorials)

1. Add openshot ppa: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonoomph/openshot-edge`
2. Update repository: `sudo apt-get update`
3. Install openshot: `sudo apt-get install openshot` (Or look in the Software Center or Synaptic)

you will find openshot in the Sound & Video Menu. You can import videos by dragging them to the openshot or by using the import option. To cut there is a Scissor Tool to "cut" the video in pieces.

I use Openshot instead of Pitivi to create Ubuntu Tutorials and Programming Tutorials for friends and let me tell you is an excellent program. It even includes a way to render the video in many formats and containers and for several services like youtube.